# Is mod_mono available for Raspbian?

Tags: mono, raspbian, mod-mono

Is mod_mono available for Raspbian, or is it possible to compile it for Raspbian?  Installing mono-complete doesn't provide the required service.  Perhaps there is another way to server .net web pages from apache2 on the RaspberryPi?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing libapache2-mod-mono package

Comment: unfortunately I get:  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-mono : Depends: mono-apache-server (< 2.10.1) but 3.0.11-1~rpi1 is to be installed or
                                mono-apache-server4 (< 2.10.1) but 3.0.11-1~rpi1 is to be installed or
                                mono-apache-server2 (< 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: OK. Try to install mono-apache-server2 first and then libapache2-mod-mono.

Comment: Sadly, I get the same result after a successful install of libapache2-mod-mono.

Comment: @andrew I don't understand. Did "mono-apache-server2" and "libapache2-mod-mono" packages get installed successfully?

Comment: mono-apache-server2 _appears_ to install successfully, with the qualification that it restarts apache2 and then hangs without exiting for a very, very long time.  If I control-c the process and run it again, I get a message that it is up to date.  So, maybe, maybe not?  When I then try to install libapache2-mod-mono, I get the same error as above.

Comment: What version of raspbian are you using?